# KVM bridging for virtual machines is not working

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, bridge, virtualization

After restarting the server, I can not ping and reach my virtual machines from the net and vice versa

> [root@pc1(192.168.0.114) ~]# ping 192.168.0.63
>   PING 192.168.0.63 (192.168.0.63) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   From 192.168.0.114 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
>   From 192.168.0.114 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
>   From 192.168.0.114 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

But I can ping them from host server where Virtual Machines are located. This server is in the same network.

> [root@vmhost]# ping 192.168.0.63
>   PING 192.168.0.63 (192.168.0.63) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.0.63: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.19 ms
>   64 bytes from 192.168.0.63: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.242 ms
>   64 bytes from 192.168.0.63: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.154 ms
>   64 bytes from 192.168.0.63: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.230 ms

Iptables services are stopped at "vmhost" and at virtual machines.

Ifconfig command from "vmhost":

> [root@vmhost network-scripts]# ifconfig
>
> **bond0**
>   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:AE:52:64:86:77
>   inet6 addr: fe80::d6ae:52ff:fe64:8677/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:1671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>             RX bytes:146143 (142.7 KiB)  TX bytes:69852 (68.2 KiB)
>
> **br0**
>   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:AE:52:64:86:77
>             inet addr:192.168.0.51  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::d6ae:52ff:fe64:8677/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:3225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>             RX bytes:225879 (220.5 KiB)  TX bytes:27689 (27.0 KiB)
>
> **br1**
>   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:AE:52:64:86:7B
>             inet addr:192.168.20.132  Bcast:192.168.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::d6ae:52ff:fe64:867b/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:58 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>             RX bytes:3769 (3.6 KiB)  TX bytes:5815 (5.6 KiB)
>
> **eth0**
>   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:AE:52:64:86:75
>             inet addr:192.168.0.140  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::d6ae:52ff:fe64:8675/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:4312 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:419278 (409.4 KiB)  TX bytes:46874 (45.7 KiB)
>   **eth1**
>   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:AE:52:64:86:77
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:486 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:26470 (25.8 KiB)  TX bytes:59228 (57.8 KiB)
>
> **eth2**
>   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:AE:52:64:86:77
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:1506 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:83 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:119673 (116.8 KiB)  TX bytes:10624 (10.3 KiB)
>
> **eth3**
>   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:AE:52:64:86:7B
>             inet6 addr: fe80::d6ae:52ff:fe64:867b/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:78 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:87 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:6219 (6.0 KiB)  TX bytes:9047 (8.8 KiB)
>
> **lo**
>   Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>             RX packets:161324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:161324 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>             RX bytes:456220429 (435.0 MiB)  TX bytes:456220429 (435.0 MiB)
>
> **vnet0**
>    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:54:00:44:71:57
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:93 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
>             RX bytes:2072 (2.0 KiB)  TX bytes:11520 (11.2 KiB)
>
> **vnet1**
>   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:54:00:FB:E9:38
>             inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fefb:e938/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
>             RX bytes:352 (352.0 b)  TX bytes:5147 (5.0 KiB)
>
> **vnet2**
>   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:54:00:EA:D8:79
>             inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:feea:d879/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:88 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:151913 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
>             RX bytes:4636 (4.5 KiB)  TX bytes:12025077 (11.4 MiB)

"ip route add" command

> **[root@vmhost]# ip route show**
>
>   192.168.0.61 dev br0  scope link
>   192.168.0.63 dev br0  scope link
>   192.168.20.0/24 dev br1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.20.132
>   192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.140
>   192.168.0.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.51
>   169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002
>   169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  scope link  metric 1040
>   169.254.0.0/16 dev br1  scope link  metric 1044
>   default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0

"brctl show" command

> [root@vmhost]# brctl show
>   bridge name bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
>   br0             8000.d4ae52648677       no              bond0
>                                                           eth1
>                                                           vnet0
>                                                           vnet2
>   br1             8000.d4ae5264867b       no              eth3
>                                                           vnet1

Information from Virtual guest machine:

*Ifconfig command*

> [root@vmguest]# ifconfig
>   **eth0**  
>   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:44:71:57
>             inet addr:192.168.0.63  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:293 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:77 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:38513 (37.6 KiB)  TX bytes:7007 (6.8 KiB)
>
> **eth1**
>   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:FB:E9:38
>             inet addr:192.168.20.130  Bcast:192.168.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:123 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:9541 (9.3 KiB)  TX bytes:1579 (1.5 KiB)
>
> **lo**
>   Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>             RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>             RX bytes:1488 (1.4 KiB)  TX bytes:1488 (1.4 KiB)

**ip route show** command

> [root@vmguest]# ip route show
>   192.168.20.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.20.130
>   192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.63
>   169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002
>   169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1003
>   default via 192.168.20.1 dev eth1

Have you got any suggestions?

Edit:
Only ARP request are comming. Like this
tcpdump -i eth1

12:28:19.232607 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.114 tell 192.168.0.63, length 28
12:28:19.232621 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.114 tell 192.168.0.63, length 28

to vnet2:
Nothing

---

I add the STP to br0. the same situation

> [root@srv01 network-scripts]# brctl show 
>   bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
>   br0             8000.d4ae52648677       yes             bond0
>                                                           eth1
>                                                           vnet0
>                                                           vnet2
>   br1             8000.d4ae5264867b       no              eth3
>                                                           vnet1

Comment: I assume `vmhost` is supposed to be receiving the echo request through `eth1` and send them through `vnet2`, which should work since both are part of `br0`. Am I understanding your intention correctly? Have you looked at `tcpdump` output on both `eth1` and `vnet2` to see if the requests are both received and sent?

Comment: This virtual machine has one inside interface eth0 and one outside interface eth1. From outside I can reach it, but I can't reach local network. I can ping interfaces on vmhost.

Comment: All virtual machines ping each other. They also ping the vmhost-bridge interface and eth0. But they can not reach the local network. Maybe routing? I can not understand where and what route I need to enter.

Comment: More information could be provided by using `ip address` instead of `ifconfig`. Don't use `ifconfig` anymore, it's deprecated and useless.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will note it. I am a newbie will Red Hat.

Answer (score 1):

Your **br0** has both **bond0** and **eth1** (a bonding slave) in it, and you have no Spanning-Tree on anything.

I suspect you have created a network loop and need to remove **eth1** from the bridge.

Comment: Not working. Do you have any suggestions? I'm tried to reinizialized interfaced.I delete bond0, br0, eth1,eth2. I created br0 with IP address. After it I have created eth1 and add it to br0. When I restarted the service, it show the message, that eth1 was already in bridge with another bridge. Where can I check, how interface are used?

Comment: Show us each of the files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`, the output of `ip addr` instead of `ifconfig`, `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0`, and `brctl show`

Answer (score 0):

Launch in your HOST those commands:

```
ip -d link show type macvtap
```

It will show all macvtap devices. After launch try this for each device:

```
sudo ip link set MACVTAP_DEVICE type macvtap mode bridge
```